# Why won't my nunit tests run in visual studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, unity-game-engine, nunit, mstest

I've got a project that builds a DLL out of some .net 3.5 C# code to be used in a unity3d project.  In the same solution, I have a project that builds a dll which contains NUnit tests.  I can run these tests in xamarin studio, but I can't debug them properly in xamarin studio.  I'm trying to build and run the tests in visual studio, where I'll actually be able to debug them.

I downloaded the NUnit Test adapter, ensured both projects are targeting Any-CPU and the same version of the .NET framework.  I also tried targeting x86.  If I try to target x64, none of the tests appear in the test explorer.

None of the tests will run.  If I start to debug it stops after a few seconds.  How do I get these tests to run in visual studio?  The tests don't call unity functions.  The dll I'm trying to test (not the DLL which contains the tests) references the unity engine dll.  I've seen that cause problems, but the tests run fine in Xamarin studio.  If I begin to run a test, this is what I see in the output window after the test fails to run:

```
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\SMDiagnostics\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\SMDiagnostics.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink\3.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Utilities.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.Measurement.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TmiAdapter.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamSystem.Licensing.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common\11.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.Common.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.TrxLogger.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\Extensions\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Extensions.VSTestIntegration.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework\10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll'
'vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe' (Managed (v2.0.50727)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1ffc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestExecutor.Core.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectAbortedException' occurred in System.ServiceModel.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in System.dll
The program '[5652] vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5652] vstest.executionengine.x86.clr20.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Some other things I tried include:
restarting visual studio
deleting the solution's .sou file
changing test> test settings > default processor architecture

Comment: Nearly impossible to tell if you can't narrow down what part of the code causes the crash and make that available for us to see. I suppose the most obvious reason would be calling a Unity method directly or indirectly that relies on Unity being properly initialized.

Comment: Read the question again.  The tests don't call unity functions.  None of my code runs.  Why do you think it has anything to do with the specifics of the code?    It seems to me to have more to do with project / configuration / visual studio settings.

Comment: "references the unity engine dll" ... makes me thing that you're using *some* functionality of Unity somewhere. I don't really understand when you say that the tests don't call unity functions but the dll you're trying to test does. If your tests run or can be made to run entirely without any references to unity, then that's what you should do. Otherwise the tested code isn't really separated from the game engine. A common problem would be trying to test code that "takes time to complete", ie requires the Unity update/fixedUpdate cycles to run. That won't be possible with nunit.

Comment: Nevertheless it won't hurt to build a minimal test project and see if that fails with the same problem. If so, post the test code here. Perhaps after all you do use Unity without realizing it? This can be subtle, for instance using a Vector3 struct from Unity.

Comment: I doubt this is a code problem and it is more of a build / configuration problem.  The BadImageFormatException can be caused by referencing 64 bit dlls in a 32 bit process.  You could try enabling [fusion logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/how-to-enable-assembly-bind-failure-logging-fusion-in-net) to see if it tells you which dlls are causing the BadImageFormatException.

Comment: John, will try fusion logging later tonight.  I'd also like to note I was able to finally debug these unit tests by loading the assembly in NUnit's GUI runner and attaching the visual studio debugger to that process.  Of course, I still want to figure out a way to not have to go through that trouble.